# Weird issue with Droid Arabic on Google Chrome for Windows

Tags: css, font-face, arabic, webfonts

I wanted to use Android fonts "Droid Arabic Kufi" and "Droid Arabic Naskh" on my website but now I have a weird issue... There are line-breaks between words!

[screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4935139/ardroid.JPG)

Could this be an issue with the font? Or is it a browser bug?
This issue didn't show up on chrome for linux.

I've converted the font using http://font2web.com.

Please help

Comment: Can you post an HTML link, or relevant code? The screen shot isn't helpful since its just an image.

Answer (score 2):

it is all about the spacing letter
set it to normal 
[code]

```
letter-spacing:normal;
```

[/code]

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your CSS. It worked for me

```
 white-space: nowrap !important
```

Comment: Yes it works but I do want my text to wrap, the issue also happens in the content not just in the titles.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `class { text-rendering: geometricPrecision; }`

This will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me like a `width` declaration on the container holding the text. The text may be wrapping down to not overflow the edge of the container.

Comment: Well, any other font works great... and the width is dynamic and not static... but this is really weird. looks like word spacing and line-height are messed up somehow!

Comment: Have you tried grabbing directly off the Google CDN: http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess (sorry about late reply).